# Custom Label with 2 icons?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a single column TableView display Labels with an icon.  What I'd like to do is add an animated icon to the label or cell so users know it's loading.  I'm not sure how to go about this.  I've looked around the internet and haven't come up with anything. I haven't had any luck trying to extend the label and customize the drawing, it's not quite as straight forward as overriding a paint method.  So if anyone could point me in the right direction on how I could achieve this effect.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/vJ3HDyf.png]

Comment: Use a custom `TableCell` by setting the `cellFactory` of your `TableColumn`. Override the `Cell#updateItem` method (read the docs!) and set the graphic to something that looks like the cells in the image.

Comment: A single column TableViewe sounds like a ListView to me?

Comment: The reason I chose a table over a listview is because I wanted the column header.

Thanks Slaw, that got me to what I needed.

Comment: @Slaw You should write more answers instead of comments ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I already posted this but in case this comes up for anyone else looking to do something similar, here was my solution:

```
    sourceColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<SourceItem, SourceItem>,TableCell<SourceItem, SourceItem>>(){

        public TableCell<SourceItem, SourceItem> call(TableColumn<SourceItem, SourceItem> param){

            TableCell<SourceItem, SourceItem> cell = new TableCell<SourceItem, SourceItem>(){

                @Override
                public void updateItem(SourceItem item, boolean empty) {

                    if (!empty) {
                        HBox box = new HBox();
                        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
                        Region spacer = new Region();
                        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);

                        box.getChildren().addAll(item.getLabel(), spacer);

                        if (item instanceof ShareSourceItem) {
                            if (((ShareSourceItem)item).isResolving()) {
                                box.getChildren().addAll(loadImage(mediaPath+"loader2.gif"));
                            }
                        }

                        setGraphic(box);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do that since the cell renderer will travel across cells and invoke paint for each cell. So I don't think you can do that and show animated icons. What you can do is to change some property of the row that is loading and invoke transition.
You can get some ideas from this code and get some similar effect:

https://github.com/james-d/Animated-Table-Row/blob/master/src/animatedtablerow/AnimatedTableRow.java